# Error CS0246 when building a C # console application

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have a console application in C #. It lies in the Git repository and, if necessary, it is downloaded by the script and is built.

```
build_script:
  - MSBuild SCADAServicesCLI/SCADAServicesCLI.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU"
```

To output logs, I use the NLog library in my project and when building my project, MSBuild displays an error stating that it is not possible to find this library.

```
AlarmWriter.cs(2,7): error CS0246: �� 㤠���� ����� ⨯ ��� ��� �����࠭�⢠ ���� "NLog" (��������, ����������� ��४⨢� using ��� ��뫪� �� ᡮ���). [D:\__build__\scada-services-cli\SCADAServicesCLI\SCADAServicesCLI\SCADAServicesCLI.csproj]
```

I already watched similar topics with such an error, but I never found the answer. I understand MSBuild does not see a link to this .dll, but I don’t know how to set it.

Comment: Is your query about the badly-encoded text, or the actual error itself?

Comment: My question is why MSBuild cannot find the NLog.dll library when building a project on another computer. On the local computer everything is built without problems.

Comment: Have a look in the csproj file how the DLL is referenced. The HintPath may be applicable to one computer but maybe not the other.

Comment: I have a link to two libraries in csproj. 1 mine which I added in manual and with it there are no problems. And the second is the NLog.dll library that I install from NuGet, and it doesn’t see it when building it.

Comment: The NLog package is not restored from NuGet. So MSBuild will not find it. Try to run `MSBuild.exe" /t:restore SCADAServicesCLI/SCADAServicesCLI.sln` as an additional step in your script before executing the build step you mentioned above.